# how can I eliminate a loop over a datatable?

Tags: r, data.table

I've two `data.table`s as shown below:

```
N = 10
A.DT <- data.table(a1 = c(rnorm(N,0,1)), a2 = NA))
B.DT <- data.table(b1 = c(rnorm(N,0,1)), b2 = 1:N)
setkey(A.DT,a1)    
setkey(B.DT,b1)
```

I tried to change my previous `data.frame` implementation to a `data.table` implementation by changing the for-loop as shown below:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(B.DT)) {
  for (j in nrow(A.DT):1) {
    if (B.DT[i,b2] <= N/2 
        && B.DT[i,b1] < A.DT[j,a1]) {
      A.DT[j,]$a2 <- B.DT[i,]$b1
      break
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, j, a2, value = -0.391987468746123) : 
  object "a2" not found
```

I think the way I access `data.table` is not quite right. I am new to it. I guess there is a quicker way of doing it than cycling up and down the two datatables.

I'd like to know if the loop shown above could be simplified/vectorised.

**Edit** The data.table data for copy/paste:

```
# A.DT
    a1  a2
1   -1.4917779  NA
2   -1.0731161  NA
3   -0.7533091  NA
4   -0.3673273  NA
5   -0.159569   NA
6   -0.1551948  NA
7   -0.0430574  NA
8   0.1783496   NA
9   0.4276034   NA
10  1.0697412   NA

# B.DT
    b1  b2
1   0.64229018  1
2   1.00527902  2
3   0.24746294  3
4   -0.50288835 4
5   0.34447791  5
6   -0.22205129 6
7   0.60099079  7
8   -0.70242284 8
9   0.6298599   9
10  0.08917988  10
```

The output I expect:

```
# OUTPUT
    a1  a2
1   -1.4917779  NA
2   -1.0731161  NA
3   -0.7533091  NA
4   -0.3673273  NA
5   -0.159569   NA
6   -0.1551948  NA
7   -0.0430574  NA
8   0.1783496   -0.50288835
9   0.4276034   0.24746294
10  1.0697412   0.64229018
```

The algorithm goes down one table, and for each row go up the other table, check some conditions and modify values accordingly. More specifically, it goes down B.DT, and for each row in B.DT goes up A.DT and assigns to a2 the first value of b1 such that b1 is smaller than a1. An additional condition is checked before assignment (b2 being equal or smaller than 5 in this example).

0.64229018 is the first value in B.DT, and it is assigned to the last unit of A.DT. 
1.00527902 is the second value in B.DT, but it is left unassigned because it is bigger than all other values in A.DT.
0.24746294 is the third value in B.DT, and it is assigned to the second last unit in A.DT.
-0.50288835 is the fourth value in B.DT, and it is assigned to unit #8 in A.DT
0.34447791 is the fifth value in B.DT, and it is left unassigned because it is too big.

This is of course a simplified problem (and therefore may not make much sense). Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: Can you explain what your loop is supposed to do? I'd like to see an output after the loop as to what you expect. And a little explanation of how. Your code is filled with errors and your output, even after fixing the errors gives something that's probably meaningless, as of now.

Comment: please **edit your original post** and *not* write code under comments.

Comment: sorry, how can I explain more....

Comment: Oh, you're fast! I had just worked out how to do it... thanks so much for your help, I understand if you think these are silly questions and apologize for wasting your time...

Comment: user22141, so far, your edit looks great. there's one thing missing. *Explain, taking one or two values, **how** you get that output value**. In other words, what's the rule?

Comment: I tried to do it. Just go down one table, and for each row go up the other table, check some conditions and modify values accordingly. Is this clearer? Matteo

Comment: `9   0.4276034   0.64229018`: here `b1` is bigger than `a1`...

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing the post. As the code is NOT working, I am doing all the computations manually. I solved my original problem using loops and data.frames (and it works), but it is quite involved (and slow) so I drastically simplified it. If you wish I can send you the code. Matteo

Answer (score 1):

Your code will run changing:

```
A.DT[j,]$a2 <- B.DT[i,]$b1
```

to

```
A.DT$a2[j,] <- B.DT[i,]$b1
```

As for more efficient use of `data.table`, I'll leave that to those more expert than I...

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it seems that your solution does not work... That's what I get: Error in `[.data.frame`(A.DT, j, a1) : object "a1" not found.... Thanks very much for your help...

Comment: Hi Alex, when using data.tables, you want to avoid using the `<-` assignment operator.  Instead, you can use `:=` inside of the `[  ]`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created your data.table, there is little need for the regular assign operator `<-`, instead you want to use `:=`, and this goes **inside** of the brackets in the `j` location. 
(the reason for avoiding `<-` is that `<-` creates a copy of the object, whereas `:=` does not, hence the efficiency)

So first modification to your code would be:

```
 # FROM: A.DT[j,]$a2 <- B.DT[i,]$b1
 # TO: 
 A.DT[j, a2 := B.DT[i, b1] ]
```

---

Now, one of `data.table`'s (many) best features is it's `by` argument, which helps do away with a lot of `for` loops and `*ply` calls. 
In this specific case, you can clean up your dual loops as follows:

```
set.seed(201)
A.DT <- data.table(a1 = rnorm(N,0,1), key="a1")  # no need to create a2 if it will be NA. If you do, make sure it is as.numeric(NA)
B.DT <- data.table(b1 = rnorm(N,0,1), b2 = 1:N, key="b2")

# Assign to a2 in A.DT
A.DT[            
      , a2 := B.DT[ b2 <= N/2 & b1 < a1] [1, b1]
      , by=a1
     ]


> A.DT
             a1         a2
 1: -2.30403431         NA
 2: -1.69658097         NA
 3: -1.28548252         NA
 4: -0.34454603 -0.6478531
 5: -0.07503189 -0.6478531
 6:  0.05593404 -0.6478531
 7:  0.18900414 -0.6478531
 8:  0.26693735  0.2238094
 9:  0.28606069  0.2238094
10:  0.32576373  0.2238094
```

---

#### Two Sidenote on `key`s.

- you can set the key at the same time as you are creating the data.table, saving you two lines of code
- a data.table is sorted by its key.  Judging by the fact that you are using row position to determine assignment, I am guessing that you will not want to set the keys as you have.  In the code above, I changed `B.DT`'s key to `b2.